# Automatically setting a DateTimeAccessed field in MongoDB (via C# MongoDriver)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Is there a convenient way to target a field (`DateTimeAccessed`, `DateTimeModified`, etc in this case, although a more generic answer would work just fine) on documents to be updated as a side-effect when they're touched by Mongo?

I could try to wrap the `mongoCollection.Find*|Remove*...` methods, or try to intercept `Query` objects, looking for the appropriate fields ($set -> add set DateTimeModified, eg), but all of this seems fairly ad-hoc and hacky. Is there a standard way to do this sort of thing without simulating a 'hook' into the DB interactions?

Answer (score 0):

I typically create a base Update method which all other methods use to start building their updates.

e.g.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the initial update builder
    /// </summary>
    private UpdateBuilder<Account> UpdateBuilder()
    {
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        return new UpdateBuilder<Account>()
                     .Set(e => e.DateTimeUtcAccessed, now)
                     .Set(e => e.DateTimeUtcModified, now);
    }
```

You could also make this a generic method and add an interface `IDateTimeStamps` to all the classes to which you want to apply this.